# Rinohtype link text is "Section 3.1" instead of the text specified in the link or link target

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rinohtype

I specify an explicit link target as follows:

```
.. _REPLY_STATUS_CODE:

REPLY_STATUS_CODE (0x0001)
---------------------------
```

Then create a reference to it like this:

```
Related
    :ref:`REPLY_STATUS_CODE`
```

And have also tried like this:

```
A :ref:`REPLY_STATUS_CODE <REPLY_STATUS_CODE>` command...
```

In both cases the text on the link is "Section 3.8" rather than "REPLY_STATUS_CODE" using Sphinx to build HTML renders the link text as "REPLY_STATUS_CODE". Is there a way to get the text I want rather than section and a number in rinohtype?

Comment: I also tried this in my stylesheet (which did the same thing):
[reference]
type=reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make rinohtype create links identical to those in HTML by adjusting the *linked reference* style:

```ini
[STYLESHEET]
name = My custom style sheet
base = sphinx

[linked reference]
type = custom
```

You can still use the [`:numref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html?highlight=numref#role-numref) role to explicitly reference elements by number (which does require setting `numfig = True`, also affecting HTML output). See issue [#244 How to restore target number references?](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/244) for more information.

Ideally, providing an explicit link text like you tried (`` :ref:`REPLY_STATUS_CODE <REPLY_STATUS_CODE>` `` ) would override the default behavior of linking sections by number, but this would require changes to docutils/Sphinx because rinohtype cannot see the difference between a reference with and without explicit link text.

Finally, it would be great to be able to define a [custom role](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles) so that rinohtype could distinguish between different types of references. For example:

```rst
.. role:: titleref(ref)
   :class: titleref
```

Alas, that isn't possible either. So, for now at least, you can only distinguish using `:ref:` and `:numref:` (which also affects HTML output).

Comment: Thanks (again), that worked just a comment that the links to ReferenceStyle docs for linked reference on this page do not work: https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html

Comment: Another approach is to use .. only:: html and .. only:: rinoh in your docs. The conditional names re pre-defined.